# Coloring points in a jitter graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I have graph where I compare the growth of a wildtype and mutant plant root in different situations. For this, I already upload my excel data in a graph with jitter and bloxpot. I like it, but  want to make all wildtype measurement in a color and mutant in other.

Here's my input:

```r
ggplot(Raiz, aes(x = G, y = T)) +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 0.5) +
geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    theme_minimal() + theme( plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
   panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    )
```

And here's how my graph is:
[image]

I wanna make 1,3,5,7... one color and 2,4,6,8... other color. Simple as that.
Can you help me please?

I tried using ChatGPT but it didnt help

---

**Data**

```r
Raiz <- structure(list(G = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"), class = "factor"), 
    T = c(0.266, 0.264, 0.253, 0.257, 0.27, 0.282, 0.273, 0.261, 
    0.265, 0.28, 0.288, 0.306, 0.272, 0.26, 0.291, 0.28, 0.276, 
    0.309, 0.267, 0.285, 0.253, 0.269, 0.256, 0.263, 0.291, 0.287, 
    0.275, 0.272, 0.273, 0.286, 0.293, 0.292, 0.289, 0.276, 0.272, 
    0.309, 0.291, 0.29, 0.272, 0.288, 0.289, 0.3, 0.28, 0.288, 
    0.286, 0.281, 0.286, 0.283, 0.28, 0.28, 0.275, 0.283, 0.285, 
    0.294, 0.283, 0.269, 0.284, 0.286, 0.273, 0.282, 0.271, 0.291, 
    0.274, 0.282, 0.279, 0.308, 0.281, 0.273, 0.298, 0.283, 0.283, 
    0.294, 0.287, 0.284, 0.276, 0.275, 0.282, 0.293, 0.295, 0.271, 
    0.284, 0.277, 0.295, 0.276, 0.282, 0.291, 0.308, 0.291, 0.274, 
    0.277, 0.281, 0.302, 0.274, 0.285, 0.653, 0.659, 0.718, 0.661, 
    0.658, 0.657, 0.646, 0.666, 0.638, 0.708, 0.712, 0.736, 0.735, 
    0.549, 0.695, 0.69, 0.585, 0.701, 0.644, 0.645, 0.632, 0.683, 
    0.591, 0.739, 0.65, 0.773, 0.669, 0.625, 0.677, 0.606, 0.655, 
    0.684, 0.667, 0.636, 0.727, 0.661, 0.726, 0.709, 0.714, 0.72, 
    0.785, 0.675, 0.77, 0.647, 0.62, 0.675, 0.677, 0.662, 0.589, 
    0.663, 0.573, 0.642, 0.599, 0.631, 0.608, 0.646, 0.693, 0.646, 
    0.642, 0.741, 0.707, 0.792, 0.652, 0.663, 0.589, 0.611, 0.614, 
    0.681, 0.757, 0.702, 0.718, 0.69, 0.666, 0.491, 0.724, 0.711, 
    0.71, 0.763, 0.746, 0.633, 0.693, 0.582, 0.675, 0.684, 0.68, 
    0.694, 0.688, 0.667, 0.623, 0.706, 0.707, 0.743, 0.684, 0.726, 
    1.11, 1.032, 1.135, 1.135, 1.126, 1.11, 1.057, 1.091, 1.137, 
    1.152, 1.132, 1.213, 1.163, 1.017, 1.075, 1.054, 1.047, 1.113, 
    1.098, 1.135, 1.142, 1.133, 1.043, 1.209, 1.152, 1.211, 1.127, 
    1.042, 1.111, 1.008, 1.142, 1.164, 1.155, 1.045, 1.148, 1.081, 
    1.144, 1.119, 1.129, 1.144, 1.121, 1.082, 1.123, 1.075, 1.037, 
    1.096, 1.081, 1.055, 0.975, 1.084, 0.914, 1.042, 0.98, 1.059, 
    1.023, 1.046, 1.075, 1.014, 1.015, 1.147, 1.159, 1.286, 1.135, 
    1.126, 1.061, 1.176, 1.085, 1.127, 1.144, 1.109, 1.101, 1.178, 
    1.082, 0.906, 1.092, 1.135, 1.151, 1.151, 1.088, 1.117, 1.148, 
    0.936, 1.164, 1.077, 1.119, 1.111, 1.037, 1.163, 1.012, 1.182, 
    1.094, 1.147, 1.137, 1.139, 1.565, 1.495, 1.58, 1.735, 1.58, 
    1.56, 1.549, 1.524, 1.581, 1.527, 1.493, 1.629, 1.531, 1.43, 
    1.509, 1.547, 1.498, 1.598, 1.603, 1.641, 1.701, 1.573, 1.525, 
    1.725, 1.585, 1.648, 1.603, 1.467, 1.508, 1.534, 1.583, 1.562, 
    1.569, 1.512, 1.591, 1.486, 1.535, 1.588, 1.535, 1.517, 1.554, 
    1.489, 1.577, 1.632, 1.502, 1.575, 1.555, 1.437, 1.479, 1.589, 
    1.337, 1.458, 1.44, 1.51, 1.402, 1.549, 1.517, 1.433, 1.484, 
    1.613, 1.662, 1.725, 1.644, 1.578, 1.43, 1.643, 1.511, 1.532, 
    1.588, 1.568, 1.53, 1.615, 1.47, 1.362, 1.477, 1.558, 1.626, 
    1.513, 1.464, 1.555, 1.464, 1.364, 1.692, 1.472, 1.545, 1.574, 
    1.505, 1.618, 1.471, 1.604, 1.542, 1.564, 1.627, 1.544, 1.986, 
    2.053, 2.044, 2.291, 2.128, 2.006, 2.016, 2.001, 2.049, 1.997, 
    1.938, 2.089, 2.029, 1.834, 1.989, 1.957, 1.957, 2.036, 2.097, 
    2.073, 2.292, 2.066, 1.977, 2.229, 2.094, 2.056, 2.086, 1.928, 
    1.981, 1.949, 2.019, 2.051, 2.036, 1.968, 1.982, 1.901, 1.874, 
    2.118, 2.007, 2.089, 1.946, 1.912, 1.99, 2.114, 2.003, 1.941, 
    1.961, 1.884, 1.886, 2.023, 1.869, 2.009, 1.945, 2.022, 1.853, 
    2.063, 1.893, 1.943, 1.92, 2.08, 2.162, 2.153, 2.103, 1.994, 
    1.885, 2.096, 2.004, 1.997, 2.013, 2.063, 1.969, 2.033, 1.893, 
    1.835, 1.923, 1.949, 2.127, 1.953, 1.906, 2.056, 2, 1.95, 
    2.003, 1.92, 2.069, 2.036, 1.991, 2.136, 1.951, 2.025, 1.962, 
    2.021, 2.074, 1.921, 2.603, 2.563, 2.561, 2.874, 2.79, 2.661, 
    2.648, 2.534, 2.556, 2.477, 2.489, 2.579, 2.574, 2.335, 2.575, 
    2.515, 2.491, 2.51, 2.68, 2.723, 3.005, 2.639, 2.554, 2.851, 
    2.737, 2.665, 2.684, 2.61, 2.544, 2.443, 2.597, 2.531, 2.552, 
    2.466, 2.438, 2.355, 2.328, 2.575, 2.509, 2.603, 2.51, 2.359, 
    2.597, 2.521, 2.498, 2.373, 2.36, 2.434, 2.439, 2.531, 2.384, 
    2.499, 2.544, 2.509, 2.369, 2.683, 2.354, 2.517, 2.458, 2.649, 
    2.745, 2.774, 2.629, 2.472, 2.353, 2.69, 2.482, 2.473, 2.471, 
    2.579, 2.554, 2.609, 2.365, 2.409, 2.356, 2.472, 2.568, 2.393, 
    2.353, 2.515, 2.431, 2.452, 2.804, 2.372, 2.677, 2.53, 2.516, 
    2.786, 2.452, 2.508, 2.505, 2.47, 2.682, 2.322, 3.154, 3.135, 
    3.105, 3.435, 3.568, 3.226, 3.235, 3.151, 3.134, 2.978, 3.004, 
    3.124, 3.084, 2.766, 3.124, 3.108, 3.085, 3.026, 3.247, 3.203, 
    3.751, 3.09, 3.11, 3.452, 3.31, 3.23, 3.295, 3.15, 3.054, 
    3.112, 3.104, 3.073, 3.114, 3.054, 2.946, 3.007, 2.882, 3.112, 
    2.96, 3.191, 2.98, 2.86, 3.175, 3.053, 2.992, 2.862, 2.87, 
    2.901, 2.992, 3.09, 2.945, 3.095, 3.111, 3.117, 2.833, 3.284, 
    2.757, 3.099, 3.07, 3.25, 3.385, 3.214, 3.179, 3.101, 2.789, 
    3.217, 3.153, 3.014, 2.955, 3.062, 2.995, 2.921, 2.873, 2.997, 
    2.973, 3.071, 3.036, 2.874, 2.806, 3.057, 2.982, 2.948, 3.282, 
    2.939, 3.191, 3.085, 3.067, 3.313, 3.02, 3.029, 3.009, 2.98, 
    3.21, 2.68, 3.912, 3.944, 3.83, 4.211, 4.302, 3.705, 3.892, 
    3.802, 3.821, 3.441, 3.747, 3.733, 3.858, 3.471, 3.772, 3.789, 
    3.791, 3.729, 3.966, 3.785, 4.592, 3.818, 3.879, 4.29, 4.158, 
    3.884, 3.985, 3.982, 3.775, 3.826, 3.766, 3.778, 3.778, 3.698, 
    3.574, 3.41, 3.536, 3.864, 3.734, 3.963, 3.62, 3.459, 3.801, 
    3.769, 3.646, 3.761, 3.826, 3.505, 3.665, 3.732, 3.617, 3.288, 
    3.845, 3.834, 3.484, 4.007, 3.313, 3.776, 3.756, 3.959, 3.98, 
    3.802, 3.67, 3.747, 3.245, 3.941, 3.9, 3.711, 3.531, 3.782, 
    3.792, 3.781, 3.554, 3.684, 3.711, 3.708, 3.694, 3.387, 3.432, 
    3.69, 3.633, 3.754, 3.903, 3.513, 3.911, 3.824, 3.494, 4.035, 
    3.712, 3.514, 3.784, 3.597, 3.919, 3.092)), row.names = c(NA, 
-752L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try changing the second argument of `ggplot` to `aes(x = G, y = T, color = c('Wildtype', 'Mutant')[2 - (G %% 2)])`

Comment: Thank you. But please have in mind that I'm going to change the 1,2,3,4... for WT or Mutant after I finish the graph. In other words, due to the excel organization, my variables arent grouped as Wildtype or mutant, but are displayed in numbers.

Can you addapt this code for the numbers, please?

Comment: That code _is_ written for numbers. It converts all odd numbers to the value `Wildtype` and all even numbers to the value `Mutant`, then maps this new variable to the color scale. If the code doesn't work for you, please include a reproducible sample of your data. You may also want to try `aes(x = G, y = T, color = c('Wildtype', 'Mutant')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])`

Comment: I did both forms but the graph didnt change. Also, the X variants name didnt change. Maybe I need another line for giving the colors to the points. 
I also didnt understand what you mean by repoducible sample of your data. You mean pasting my excel here?
Thank you for your help anyway. I just learned how to use R this thrusday.

Comment: Reproducible data means some data that we can copy-paste into our consoles to test and verify solutions. If you type `dput(Raiz)` into your console, you will get a big text output that you can copy-paste into your question to give us enough information to help you.

Comment: It is too long. I will post for a brief time as a answer so you can copy it. Allright?

Comment: I have posted an answer showing that my second suggestion works just fine with the data you provided.

Comment: Thank you.
Is there a way to change the color. Instead of red and blue using color codes?

Comment: Yes, add `+ scale_color_manual(values = c(Wildtype = 'pink', Mutant = 'orange'))` to your plot (or whatever colors you like)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```r
ggplot(Raiz, aes(x = G, y = T, 
                 color = c('Wildtype', 'Mutant')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(color = 'Type')
```

[image]

Comment: Man, thank you so so much! I really appreciate it.